# explain this line of code android

Tags: java, android

I am beginner to android, I am looking at this tutorial and came accross this code:

```
int temp = (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) ? 1 : 0;
```

can some one explain this for me.

May be this question is duplicate, but I don't know what to search for.
It will be great if you can tell me what it is in C# aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) ? 1 : 0;
```

means

```
int result;
if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    result = 1;
else
    result = 0;
```

Comment: Where the ternary operator is more efficient, because that is most likely going to be compiled to a CCMOV (Conditional Move), which won't be suffering from branch prediction failure.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure as what you want to be explained, but it seems that you are not understand/knowing about the `ternary operator` in Java.

It essentially means:

```
if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
    temp = 1;
}
else {
    temp = 0;
}
```

Furthermore, I am unsure if this is correct Java code. It seems like you have left out something of your question, as the ternary operator most likely belongs to either an assignment or a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the parenthesis, question mark, and colon, then... it goes like so

```
(Condition ? If_condition_is_true_do_this : otherwise_do_this);
```

Exactly like doing this:

```
if(Condition)
  If_condition_is_true_do_this
else
  otherwise_do_this
```

And it is the same syntax in C#;

Answer (score 1):

This is Java, not C# but ternary operators exist there as well.

About ternary operators, click [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a).

What the (full) code (not your snippet) does here is to check the `sensor` variable for equality with class constant `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and assign the missing variable on the left with 1 if they are equal or 0 otherwise.